# Deserialize List of object Json with Gson

Tags: java, json, list, parsing, gson

I have the next Json :

```
{"total":1,"min":20,"sort":"","count":20,"houses":[{"logo":"house1.jpg","name":"Springfield","age":100}]
```

The class House is the next :

```
public class House{
    private String logo;
    private String name;
    private int age;
}
```

And I want to obtain the list of House. I tried with the next code :

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
List<House> rest = gson.fromJson(JsonString, new TypeToken<List<House>>(){}.getType());
```

But it doesnt work, the progam is in stuck.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If i were you i create a new class such as:

```
public class YourNewObject
{
    private int total;
    private int min;
    private int count
    private List<House> houses;
}
```

And then use this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
YourNewObject houses =  gson.fromJson(JsonString, YourNewObject.class);
```

That should work.

Regards